# People Result Source in SharePoint 2013 not returning results

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-on-prem, result-source

People Result Source doesn't return any results whereas other result sources return results I wonder why.

Couple of things I would like to mention

1) MySites is not used in company even though we do have the webapp
2) I navigated to peopleresults.aspx and modified the "Peopl Search Core Results" and changed the query to one attached in image below but still no results.

Please advise if I am doing anything wrong.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need a Profile content source. Are you crawling the User Profile Service on SPS3 or SPS3S?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have set up everything for mysite and people search.

could you verify that you did everything of the following:

> The process is similar but there are a few things to be aware of.  People Search requires you to have the User Profile Service Application up and running as well as My Sites.  If you don’t have either of those configured, People Search will not work and you will likely see an error like the following in your crawl log.

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/01/03/how-to-set-up-people-search-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

And also could you just try to create a mysite site collection for one user and then crawl the mysite and check if that particular user can be found? My feeling (not 100% sure) is, that people can't be found if the user has not MySite site collection.